# Saving an "order" to the database,order saves,but the " Order Lines" do not

Tags: spring, hibernate

So I have an "Order" that contains information like the user who made the order,date order was made,the user who made it etc.The order also contains "Order Lines".I was under the impression when using hibernate "save" it would also save the "Order Lines" but it only inserts the order.

Orders.java

```
@Entity
public class Orders {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

Date date;
private double price;
private String address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
private List<OrderLine> orderLines = new ArrayList<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public List<OrderLine> getOrderLines() {
    return orderLines;
}

public void setOrderLines(List<OrderLine> orderLines) {
    this.orderLines = orderLines;
}
}
```

OrderLine.java

```
@Entity
public class OrderLine {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "orders_id")
private Orders order;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private Product product;

int quantity;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Orders getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(Orders order) {
    this.order = order;
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

}

OrderDAO.java

```
@Repository
public interface OrderDao extends CrudRepository<Orders,Long> {
Orders save(Orders order);
}
```

OrderController,second method is the relevant method being called

```
 @Controller
 public class OrderController {
 @Autowired
 private Cart cart;
@Autowired
private OrderService orderService;
@RequestMapping("/completeOrder")
public String completOrder() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if((auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
        //user isnt  logged in already,cant complete order,redirect back to cart
        return "redirect:/cart";
    }
    if(cart.getLines().size()==0){
        //nothing in the cart,cant complete order,redirect to cart,
        return "redirect:/cart";
    }
    return "completeOrder";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/completeOrder/complete",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String completOrderComplete(@RequestParam("address") String address, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if((auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
        //user isnt  logged in already,cant complete order,redirect back to cart
        return "redirect:/cart";
    }
    if(cart.getLines().size()==0){
        //nothing in the cart,cant complete order,redirect to cart,
        return "redirect:/cart";
    }
    if(address.length()<10){
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash",new FlashMessage("Address entered was too short", FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
        return "redirect:/completeOrder";
    }
    //logged in user
    User user = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
    ArrayList<OrderLine> orderLines = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CartLine> cartLines = (ArrayList<CartLine>) cart.getLines();
    Orders order = new Orders();
    order.setAddress(address);
    order.setUser(user);

    for(int i = 0;i<cartLines.size();i++){
        OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
        orderLine.setProduct(cartLines.get(i).getProduct());
        orderLine.setQuantity(cartLines.get(i).getQuantity());
        orderLines.add(orderLine);
    }
    order.setOrderLines(orderLines);
    order.setPrice(1000);
 //get current date time
    Date date = new Date();
    order.setDate(date);
    orderService.save(order);
    return "/";
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use cascade attribute in your definition for orderLines variable like this:

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List orderLines = new ArrayList<>();

You have multiple options for cascading which you can find in 
https://www.google.com.hk/amp/howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/amp/.

Comment: I added CascadeType.PERSIST and the "ORDER_ID" FIELD IN the added fields in the database for the table "ORDERLINE" is null

Comment: You have to set order for each orderline in the for loop where you are creating orderLine object(orderLine.setOrder(order)).